# How to find out the port and the folder that which contains the info about the USB Device is plugged in?

Tags: linux, usb

In my application, I specifically want to power off the mouse (if connected), Hence to do that I have to change the file permissions for the file named "autosuspend" and "level" and write to it in

> /sys/bus/usb/device/the-folder-for-mouse.

How do I find out the folder name for the **the-folder-for-mouse?**

[The same question asked be me over here but unanswered.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450440/how-to-find-out-the-port-and-the-folder-that-which-contains-the-info-about-the-u)

Comment: Could the downvoters please tell me why they are downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
lsusb
```

or you can monitor input events from USB and other devices via:

```
evtest
```

which will also tell you the device path (e.g. mouse and keyboard, as well as power button, etc.) in `/dev/input/event*`. You might need to install the evtest package for that.